# Check for IP address in table - mySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Alright. I have this contest signup form with 3 fields that inserts it into a mySQL DB... as well as emailing it. I am adding this code that will check the form for the users current IP, and disallow the submission if it exists.

This seems to be executing without error now... but it allows multiple submissions from the same IP. Anything jump out as incorrect?

FULL CODE BELOW:

```
<?php //include the connection file

require_once('connection.php');


function sanitize($value, $type)
{
$value = (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? addslashes($value) : $value;

switch ($type) {
case "text":
$value = ($value != "") ? "'" . $value . "'" : "NULL";
break;
case "long":
case "int":
$value = ($value != "") ? intval($value) : "NULL";
break;
case "double":
  $value = ($value != "") ? "'" . doubleval($value) . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $value = ($value != "") ? "'" . $value . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
}

return $value;
}

//save the data on the DB and send the email

if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'submitform')
{
//recieve the variables

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$ip = gethostbyname($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
$QUERY = "SELECT COUNT(IP) AS `count` FROM `contest` WHERE IP = 'value'";
$RESULT = mysql_query($QUERY) or die(mysql_error());

// Read the firs row
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($RESULT);

// Check how many rows MySQL counted
if($row['count'] > 0) {
echo "value already exists";
}
else {

//save the data on the DB

mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

$insert_query = sprintf("INSERT INTO contest (First_Name, Last_Name, Email_Address, Date, ip) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, NOW(), %s)",
                        sanitize($firstname, "text"),
                        sanitize($lastname, "text"),
                        sanitize($email, "text"),
                        sanitize($ip, "text"));

$result = mysql_query($insert_query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

if($result)
{
    //send the email

    $to = "EMAIL ADDY";
    $subject = "SUBJECT LINE";

    //headers and subject
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0rn";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1rn";
    $headers .= "From: ".$firstname." <".$email.">rn";

    $body = "New contact
";
    $body .= "First Name: ".$firstname."
";
    $body .= "Last Name: ".$lastname."
";
    $body .= "Email: ".$email."
";
    $body .= "IP: ".$ip."
";

    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

    //ok message

    header ('Location: thanks.html');
    exit ();
}
}
}

?>
```

Comment: What kind of problems do you have? (And why are these single-quotes there in that line?)

Comment: Use of the inet MySQL functions might be something to look into too. [See this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton).

Comment: That might not be a good idea. I live in a university town; all the students who live on campus share a single, public-facing IP address.

Comment: Catcall: I am still going to go with this as most people would be varied throughout the country...

it seems to be running without error now... it allows multiple submissions though. hmmm. I updated code above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use backticks instead of single quotes to escape table names/reserved words:

```
$QUERY = "SELECT COUNT(IP) AS `count` FROM `contest` WHERE IP = 'value'";
```

Also if your IP column is string you need to enclose the value for *that* in single quotes :-)

Comment: aliases don't need to be quoted. You can alias anything you want to a reserved word - it's only when the usage is ambiguous, such as `SELECT order FROM`... is that a query with a huge chunk missing in the middle and also missing the 'by fieldname', or an actual field named 'order'?

Comment: @MarcB: So is the above code invalid? Does it answer the question or not?

Comment: The code isn't incorrect, but saying that all 'reserved words' need escaping is. Only in some places do you have to escape them. Your sample isn't one of them.

Comment: Seems like a correct answer to my original question. Just brings up a whole set of new ones as my code is still not serving it's purpose, yet surprisingly runs error free.

Comment: @MarcB: Thanks for clarifying, I've just had a peek at the docs and you're spot on. You learn something new every day, eh? :-)